# Getting a Error:Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in *****

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I have started reading SuperBible OpenGL 5th Edition. I have installed Visual C++ 2010.
I have tried the very first programme in the book . Rendering a triangle. However when I write the same code into C++ IDE and when I compile it I am getting the following error.

Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in MyFirstOpenGLProgramme.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

The very first line triangle.Begin(GT_TRIANGLES, 3); is failing .

Can any guide me through this.

Comment: -1: There is not nearly enough information presented here to know what you're doing wrong. If you aren't familiar with C++ and using C++ compilers, then you need to become familiar with that _before_ getting into graphics programming in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you posted some example code.  You might try looking through the [book's errata](http://code.google.com/p/oglsuperbible5/issues/list).

Specifically, [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/oglsuperbible5/issues/detail?id=3) has comments that seem similar to what you're experiencing and appear to be caused by using hardware that does not support the required OpenGL functionality.

Comment: Do I need to include libraries or dlls of OPENGL_ES too into my Environment as I did for FREEGLUT and GLTOOLS. 

While debugging I have observed that the code in the PreProcess of 

#ifdef OPENGL_ES
....
#endif 

in GLBatch.cpp is actually creating a problem.

Thanks.